# Riemann Integration related to Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I am a beginner in Riemann Integration. Can someone please help me do the following problem?

Let $P$ be the Cantor Set(the most general one i.e. removing the middle $\frac{1}{3}$rd portion in each of the infinite iterations). Let $f$ be a bounded real function on $[0,1]$ which is continuous at every point outside $P$ .
Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on$[0,1]$

Comment: are we allowed to use $\int_P f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{P_n} f(x) dx =  0$  as a proof ? ( where $P_n$ is a sequence of set converging to $P$)

Comment: @user1952009 : Sorry, but I haven't come across that proof yet.. Can you be elaborate please?

Comment: ok. so $P_n$ is the sequence of sets as explained in your post, $P = \lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$ and $P_{n+1} \subset P_n$. now consider the function $f_n(x) = f(x)$ if $x \in P_n$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise.  finally consider $F_n(x) = \int_0^x f_n(y) dy$ and show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x)$ exists and that its derivative is $f(x)$ for $x \not\in P$